# Como descobrir endereço do servidor numa aplicação Android

Tags: android

Boa noite!

Estou com um app aqui, e preciso descobrir os dados do servidor para onde está sendo enviado os cadastros. É mysql (url/phpmyadmin). O problema é que não acho em lugar nenhum. Cheguei mais perto aqui:

```
e = function() {
        var t = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open,
            n = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(n, i, e, o, r) {
            this._method = n, this._url = i, t.call(this, n, i, e, o, r)
        }, XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(t) {
            function i() {
                if (4 == o.readyState) {
                    var t = (new Date).getTime(),
                        n = t - e,
                        i = {
                            method: r,
                            url: a,
                            latency: n.toString(),
                            httpStatusCode: o.status.toString(),
                            responseDataSize: o.responseText.length
                        };
                    mintBridge.logNetwork(i.method, i.url, i.latency, i.httpStatusCode, i.responseDataSize)
                }
            }
            var e, o = this,
                r = this._method,
                a = this._url;
            e = (new Date).getTime(), this.addEventListener("readystatechange", i, !1), n.call(this, t)
        }
    },
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz? Obrigada! ;)

Comment: isso é uma aplicação cordova/ionic/onsen ou algo parecido, correto? consegues debugar no navegador? Penso que a resposta que precisa esta nesse objeto i

Comment: Obrigada. O App eu baixei do Play Store Console, tenho o APK na minha máquina. Como eu "debugaria"?